# Amazon RDS replicate and addressing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I've just started to deploy an application on multiple EC2 instances in multiple regions. On each instance I have the same application which need to access an RDS instance. To have a good access time on my RDS instance, I use replicates.

But I'm wondering how can I deploy each copy of my application on each server without adding an extra configuration to tell wich RDS/replicate my application should use.

I've think on using Router53 but I don't know where to start. Any idea?

Comment: You're going to have to configure each application instance to tell it what database to use somehow. Instance metadata could be one way to pass in a parameter.

Comment: I didn't want to do that that, because it makes a lot of configuration. I ended doing some geolocation routing with Route53 ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Route53 is the way to go.

Route53 can do geolocation routing. So, you could setup records in Route53 for each geographic area that points to the local RDS instance name.

Only "drawback" is that Route53 will have to take over for DNS on your domain, unless you use some alternative domain name dedicated for this where it doesn't matter.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html

Comment: I end up delegating the management of a subdomain to Route53. Then using geolocation routing. And it's work perfectly, thanks :)